# How to get size and resolution on image that already in bytes

Tags: python, image, byte, size

i want to know if there some way to get the size and resolution of the image that already in bytes in python, i tried to search about it and it was using an external library.. did you know how to do it by external libraries or not.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PIL (pillow).

to install it run "pip install pillow" on your terminal:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

image_data = ... # byte values of the image
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
print(f'{image.height}, {image.width}')
```